# Installing python's numpy

Tags: python

I am trying to install numpy. I followed the solutions provided by a lot of similar questions in this site. Generally the process is fairly straightforward:

`sudo apt-get install python-numpy`

I execute this line. After installing I run python and I import numpy:

`import numpy`

But it doesn't recognize it! What is the problem? How can I install it correctly?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its because you may have installed a numpy for python 2.x series and since you are using python 3.x, it won't work. You should install the python3-numpy package for it to work properly.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! There was nowhere else any mention of Python3 Numpy.

Comment: You are welcome. This difference in the names of python packages for different versions of python is very common in Ubuntu and Debian, to differentiate easily. Used to baffle me too earlier.